# How can i parse a txt file into lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not far from a new bee in Python and i would like to parse a file
as is :

```
Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain
Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain
Marseille, 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion
Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins
Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens
```

The file contains : City, Street number, Street Type and Street Name

This order is always the same and the City is followed by a comma.

I had done this for now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4                                                                          

import readline
import sys

try:
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
except:
    sys.exit()

lines = f.readlines()
print(lines)
```

And i get this output:

```
['Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain\n', 'Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain\n', 'Marseille, 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion\n', 'Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins\n', 'Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens\n']
```

Seems to be the thing to do but now i have 2 questions:

1. How can I make some lists for each one of the type (City, number, streetType, streetName) ?
2. Is there a librairy in Python that parses adresses in a list ? One that you would recommend ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) in Python?

Comment: 1st question:- How can I make some lists for each one of the type:::-- It's already a list of addresses. What else do u want?

Comment: I am quite new to it but i have basic knowledge in programming so i think i could check this out and understand it .. i hope

Comment: Ok maybe i forgot to tell you guys the goal of the project is to make a basic autocomplete from words that we get from that famous .txt file.

Comment: Think through your design first.  Do you really want a list of house numbers?  For example, a dictionary of street names as keys each with a list of house numbers might be useful.

Comment: Which famous .txt file?

Comment: The one containing the City names, numbers, streetTypes and streetNames .

Comment: Thank you @cdarke , this is really a good idea of design ! I think i'll go this way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various data structures that you could store this data in. You could store the data from each line in a tuple containing (city_name, street_number, street_type, street_name), and then store each of those tuples into a list. A slightly nicer option is to store the data into a list of dictionaries. Here's a short demo.

```
fname = 'citydata.txt'

addresses = []
keys = ('city', 'num', 'type', 'name')

with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        city, line = line.split(',', 1)
        num, street_type, street_name = line.split(None, 2)
        t = (city, num, street_type, street_name)
        print(t)
        addresses.append(dict(zip(keys, t)))

print()
for row in addresses:
    print(row)

print()
for row in addresses:
    print(row['num'])
```

**output**

```
('Paris', '458', 'boulevard', 'Saint-Germain')
('Paris', '343', 'boulevard', 'Saint-Germain')
('Marseille', '343', 'boulevard', 'Camille Flammarion')
('Marseille', '29', 'rue', 'Camille Desmoulins')
('Marseille', '1', 'chemin', 'des Aubagnens')

{'city': 'Paris', 'num': '458', 'type': 'boulevard', 'name': 'Saint-Germain'}
{'city': 'Paris', 'num': '343', 'type': 'boulevard', 'name': 'Saint-Germain'}
{'city': 'Marseille', 'num': '343', 'type': 'boulevard', 'name': 'Camille Flammarion'}
{'city': 'Marseille', 'num': '29', 'type': 'rue', 'name': 'Camille Desmoulins'}
{'city': 'Marseille', 'num': '1', 'type': 'chemin', 'name': 'des Aubagnens'}

458
343
343
29
1
```

Comment: What an answer ! Thanks it really helps my understanding of this language.

Comment: Last question is : I am currently learning C and C++ and i was wondering if there was a same kind of "error handling" as in C or C++. By that I mean checking returns of open() or other functions ? Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Use Exception handling in Python - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: @ThomasBeaudet: I'm glad you like my answer. Don't forget to upvote it, once you have enough points. :) Yes, Python has exception handling. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Python works at a higher level than C/C++. For example, I have used `with` to open the file. This automatically closes the file if there is some error inside the `with` block. In C you'd need to do a lot more explicit error checking.

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT)

Actually you don't need any extra libs. It is simple operation which could be done with list comprehension or generator or `map` function and `split` , `strip` `str` object methods if you could split by the single character

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
    split = lambda x: x.replace(',', '').split()
    addresses_lists = map(split, lines)
```

If you have more complex condition to split - use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module to parse a pattern you need. Definitely you need [`split` function from `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Note that this does not strip the comma off the city name.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yep it could be processed after or with more complex lambda used with map for example.

Comment: No need, both answers helped me a lot since i'm really new to Python ! i'll just gather every possible infos i can ! Again, thanks a lot guys !

Comment: @PM2Ring, but you had a good point and more obvious syntax. That is good for studying ;)